# How to track down randomly dropped keys on text input in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, user-input

SYMPTOM
I have a C# + WPF application that has complex a XAML scene. Some buttons in the application will open a modal dialog with a TextBox that prompts the user to enter some text.  I have observed that sometimes keys will be dropped.  For example, if I type "abcdef" I might just get "abdef".

Some other observations about reproducing the issue:

- is is more noticeable if you type in keys faster
- it is more likely when I have a more complex scene

ANALYSIS NOTES
Some things that I have tried or observed:

1. the TextBox definitely does not receive any TextInput event
2. if I hook into ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage I can see that the events are also missing: we are NOT getting the WM_KEYDOWN or WM_CHAR for the missing keys.  We are getting WM_KEYUP.
3. Snoop shows the same. There is a missing "KeyDown", but we do get the "KeyUp"
4. if I hook into Win32 SetWindowsHookEx(), then the events are not missing:  we get WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP.
5. I was wondering if a possible cause was doing too much work in the UI thread.  I added a remote Thread monitor and output StackTraces when I saw hitches, but nothing obvious there. I actually fixed a couple of the hitches observed and the problem persists.

REPRO
Setting up a minimal repro hasn't been successful so far. If I can get an idea what part of the application seems to be related, then I can try to exaggerate that.  In the meantime, I am looking for some insight:

1. What can lead to this problem?
2. How can I track down what could be the cause?

ASIDE
Point (4) does potentially give me a workaround. When my TextBox gets focus, I could use SetWindowsHookEx() to make sure I don't miss any keys, but obviously that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: This problem is impossible to solve without a minimal reproducible example. It could be anything. It sounds like your UI thread is exhausted and not able to process the input events properly. You could incrementally disable some UI features to see what is causing this. Or reverse the process and start with a blank project and add the features until you are able to reproduce it. this way you can present a minimal reproducible example that we can review. Or just review your code and pay attention to any intensive work like iterations and check if async APIs are properly used.

Comment: @BionicCode I was hoping to get some insight as to what could lead to this symptom, to get an idea of how to either diagnose it or setup a repro. I was hoping there was a way to get a list of every hook that might be subscribed to the key events. Your comment "sounds like your UI thread is exhausted" is helpful.

Since the app is complex, I believe the suggestion to "incrementally disable" is the right way to go. Looking closer, there are some libraries that are being loaded and it's possible they are hooking into windows messages, so I'll probably start there (turning them off).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I originally posted this I was hoping to get some information on whether hitches in the UI thread can lead to this symptom. I should have been more clear.  I found various tools and techniques to identify those, but in the end they were not the problem.  I have heard that it is true that you can drop messages if you have too much processing in the UI thread, but I haven't found any details. E.g. 100ms? 1000ms? Also, I suspect that if that were the case, you would probably be losing a lot of messages, not an intermittent one.

Incrementally disabling features was the best way to go. Turns out there was a library being loaded that apparently was hooking into the message loop and has a bug that intermittently a key down event would be incorrectly consumed.  This happened before the message got to WPF, so Snoop didn't even see the message.

To answer my original questions.

1. The answer is that code somewhere that hooks into the message loop.
2. I could not find any diagnostic tools to find out what was subscribing to or consuming messages outside of WPF.